# Calculating equations of polars regarding a circle

Tags: geometry

Let be $$x^2+y^2=1635 $$ a circle around the origin and $p_1=(13,39)$ and $p_2=(10,39) $.

I want to calculate the equations of the polars of $p_1$ and $p_2$ regarding the circle and also the equation of tangents through point $p_1$ onto the circle.

Now I roughly scetched the polars of $p_1$ and $p_2$. They must be just outside the circle.
But how do I set up/ find the equations for the polars  exactly?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to calculate polars for $p_1$ and $p_2$? Of course, both are not on the circle, and actually $x^2+y^2=1635$ has no integer solutions.

Comment: I want to determine the equations for the polars because that is a geometry task and I would like to know how to solve such a task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the polar of point $(x_1,y_1)$ wrt the circle $x^2+y^2=k$ is simply $x_1 x+y_1 y=k$.

So the polars you want are $13x+39y=1635$ and $13x+39y=1635$.

For a point $(p,q)$ on a circle, the tangent is the same as the polar.  So the tangent line at $(p,q)$ is $px+qy=1635$.  You want to find $(p,q)$ such that the tangent runs through $p_1$, i.e. $13p+39q=1635$.

This means that you have to solve for $p,q$ in the equations
$$
\begin{align}
13p+39q &= 1635 \\
p^2+q^2 &= 1635
\end{align}
$$

This reduces to solving a quadratic equation so you will have two solutions for $(p,q)$ and the corresponding tangents.